# Use data on JSON with cells

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've got this JSON from an API:

```
{
    "oldest": "2019-01-24T00:00:00+00:00",
    "activities": [
        {
            "message": "<strong>Henrik</strong> didn't resist a guilty pleasure at <strong>Starbucks</strong>.",
            "amount": 2.5,
            "userId": 2,
            "timestamp": "2019-05-23T00:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "message": "<strong>You</strong> made a manual transfer.",
            "amount": 10,
            "userId": 1,
            "timestamp": "2019-01-24T00:00:00+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

It has a lote more activities. How can I access it and fill my cells with its data? So far I've got this code:

MainViewController:

```
struct Activities: Decodable {
    var oldest: String
    var activities: [Activity]
}

struct Activity: Decodable {
    var message: String
    var amount: Float
    var userId: Int
    var timestamp: String
}

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {

    var activityList: [Activities] = []
    var activity: [Activity] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.prefetchDataSource = self

        let activitiesJSONURLString = "https://qapital-ios-testtask.herokuapp.com/activities?from=2016-05-23T00:00:00+00:00&to=2019-05-23T00:00:00+00:00"
        guard let activitiesURL = URL(string: activitiesJSONURLString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: activitiesURL) { (data, response, err) in
            // perhaps check err
            // also perhaps check response status 200 OK

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                // Activities
                let activities = try JSONDecoder().decode(Activities.self, from: data)

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json: ", jsonErr)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activityList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActivityCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

        return cell
    }

    // Prefetching
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
//        if indexPaths.contains(where: isLoadingCell) {
//            viewModel.fetchModerators()
//        }
    }
}
```

But I think something is off. Or I have no clue on how to start. I could really use some help or any tips you can give me. Please and thank you!

Comment: not related to your question but you should only reload the table view data in case the decoder succeeds.

Comment: Thanks! Moved the reloadData to the Do block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the naming of the structs is pretty confusing. Name the root object with something unrelated like `Response` or `Root`.

And we are going to decode the timestamps as `Date`

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    var oldest: Date
    var activities: [Activity]
}

struct Activity: Decodable {
    var message: String
    var amount: Float
    var userId: Int
    var timestamp: Date
}
```

Second of all as the data is received in all the conformance to `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` is pointless. Remove it and delete also the `prefetchRowsAt` method.

Declare only one data source array and name it `activities`

```
var activities = [Activity]()
```

and delete

```
var activityList: Activities!
```

In the completion handler of the data task decode `Root` and assign the activities array to the data source array

```
 do {
    // Activities
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    self.activities = result.activities

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
 } catch {
    print("Error serializing json: ", error)
 }
```

The table view data source methods are

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return activities.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActivityCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    let activity = activities[indexPath.row]
    // assign the activity data to the UI for example
    // cell.someLabel = activity.amount
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. A couple of things: 1) I actually  want Prefetching, I just put it there to do it later. 2) `var message: Date` should be a `String`, but I think that was just a mistake. 3) As you can see, the message of an activity has some HTML to it (`<strong></strong>`) so if I use `cell.descriptionLabel.text = activity.message` I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/mp3W5xa.png), do I have to use NSAttributedString or something like that? Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: 2) Yes it was a mistake. 3) If you want to consider the HTML format you have to convert it to `NSAttributedString`. Either add an extra *singleContainer* struct or write a custom initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the `activityList` to determine the number of rows, I'm assuming that you want to use the data from `activityList` in order to populate your `ActivityCell`s. That is, unless, you meant for activityList to be a single instance of `Activities` instead of an array of `Activities`, in which case you would likely use `activityList.activities.count` in order to determine the number of rows. In either case, lets just call the array of data you want to use to fill the cells `activityList`.

In this case, you should make sure to update `activityList` to the activities that you have fetched from the API. Once you have the `activityList`, you can then use `reloadData` which will trigger your table view delegate methods. In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you can then use `activityList` in order to update the dequeued cell.

Something like this might be what you want:

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {

    var activityList: Activities!
    var activity: [Activity] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.prefetchDataSource = self

        let activitiesJSONURLString = "https://qapital-ios-testtask.herokuapp.com/activities?from=2016-05-23T00:00:00+00:00&to=2019-05-23T00:00:00+00:00"
        guard let activitiesURL = URL(string: activitiesJSONURLString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: activitiesURL) { (data, response, err) in
            // perhaps check err
            // also perhaps check response status 200 OK

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                // Activities
                let activities = try JSONDecoder().decode(Activities.self, from: data)
                self.activityList = activities

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json: ", jsonErr)
            }

        }.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activityList.activities.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActivityCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
        if let activity = activityList?[indexPath.row] {
            // UPDATE CELL ACCORDING TO activity
         }
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your response. But on line `let activityForCell = activityList[indexPath.row]` I get `Value of optional type 'Activities?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type 'Activities'`